# "operator expected after expression" when using dynamic openList/1

Tags: prolog, syntax-error

I'm trying to call the following at the top of my prolog file.

```
:- dynamic openList/1, dynamic closedList/1.
```

But this results in the following syntax error.

```
syntax error: . or operator expected after expression
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ISO Prolog only the following forms are legal:

```
:- dynamic(openList/1).
:- dynamic(closedList/1).
```

or

```
:- dynamic([openList/1,closedList/1]).
```

or (strangely, and not recommended)

```
:- dynamic((openList/1,closedList/1)).
```

Some Prologs will also allow (not portable)

```
:- dynamic openList/1, closedList/1.
```

Comment: "strangely, and not recommended" is your opinion, it has nothing to do with ISO.